# AmCharts Serial: How to break lines by long labels?

Tags: css, amcharts

I have a horizontal SerialChart with AmCharts:

When displayed at a desktop browser, everything looks fine:

[image]

> But when i'm resizing, the bars are getting smaller, but the text
>   stays the same:

[image]

> Is there a way of resizing the categoryAxis as well so i see the bars
>   in a mobile screen? Or move the Labels on top of the bars when i'm
>   viewing them on mobile?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will help to you.

```
"categoryAxis": {
              "ignoreAxisWidth": true,
               "autoWrap": true
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this example I have just done, http://jsfiddle.net/17xraeue/, you will see that I have added a line break in standard HTML tags, BR, into the name.

```
"dataProvider": [
  {
    "country": "All Other<br>Countries",
    "visits": 441,
    "color": "#CD0D74"
  }
]
```

To make this work dymanically without having to add line breaks in yourself you could also use a scripting langauge such as PHP to add them for you.

```
<?
//See http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php for more details
//wordwrap([text string], [number of characters before line break], [HTML to use for line break]);
echo wordwrap("this is my text string", 20, "<br />");
?>
```

Comment: <br> is not working for AmCharts 3 and higher.